# PHP: Serialize vs Singleton vs Dependency Injection vs something else?

Tags: php, serialization, dependency-injection, singleton

I've to objects in my code that I always want to access when I need them.
A database object, which holds the connection to the database. This is a static object, the connection won't change.
And I've a user object, which holds the user level, username and id.

I read some posts and articles about the way how to to this. I found 3 solutions
- using a singleton
- serialize object and store it in session
- use dependency injection.

Singleton is bad because globals are bad.
Serialize an object and store it in a session seems ugly to me (don't exactly know why)
Using Dependency injection makes your constructor crowded with parameters.

Now I've two questions
- Is there another way that I didn't mention?
- What is the best method to grant overall access to objects mentioned above?

Comment: Serialize isn't a good idea for a database object... resources like the database connection can't be serialized

Answer (score 1):

You are messing up everything.

> What is the best method to grant overall access to objects mentioned above?

### No, there is no such method at all

They are different objects and require different treatment.

for the database object you have but little choice.
You can create it with every request and use it throughout processing (of course you will need to make it global to use inside other classes).
Or use it as a *static singleton object,* which will be called each time you need to interact with database. It will establish a database connection at the first call and eventually use it until the end of the processing request. With another request it will start over.

For the user object both *transparent* serializing in a session and dependency injection are good.
However, creating a user object on each request is not that bad idea. In your place  I won't torture sessions such a way.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry about a hard Reality but you use specialized words from Software Development but you don't have the Know-how ... DI can use the constructor or maybe a setter Method ... Also you can use a DI Container like pimple, synfony or flow3 ... Or Write an own.

We work on an internal framework where we disallow singletons, direct Session Access is. Also well -> may Be you have to lern about Architecture.

There are some good Books available.